# Migrating from graphite to graph-explorer

Tags: vimeo, graphite, statsd

The graphite-webapp does not encourage ad-hoc graphing. Graphiti et al are just fancy UIs that, while improve UI-UX, do not do much regarding the inherent linear metric search that plagues the graphite-webapp. Correct me if wrong here, but the *only* option I came across that encourages ad-hoc graphing has been [Graph-Explorer](http://vimeo.github.io/graph-explorer/). Assuming, that Graph-Explorer is the only way ahead.

I have some 1000 distinct metrics currently. Named in the following fashion-

`stats.beta.pluto.ip-10-0-1-81.helios.pa.v4.reminder.total`

`stats.beta.pluto.ip-10-0-1-81.helios.pa.v4.reminder.failed`

`stats.beta.pluto.ip-10-0-1-81.helios.pa.v4.reminder.delivered`

`stats.dev.ganglia.ip-10-0-3-40.ink.web.pi.notification.android.total
stats.dev.ganglia.ip-10-0-3-40.ink.web.pi.notification.android.failed
stats.dev.ganglia.ip-10-0-3-40.ink.web.pi.notification.android.delivered`

I understand that these will become-

`metric=stats.env=dev.role=ganglia.server=ip-10-0-3-40. application=ink.endpoint=web.src=pi.metric=notification.what=total`

Where do I insert `unit` and `target_type` tags?

Similarly, I have 500 timers.

1. How do I go about migrating from 'proto1' to 'proto2'?
2. Also where exactly does [Carbon-Tagger](https://github.com/vimeo/carbon-tagger/wiki) come into the stack?
3. Do I rename my metrics at the source level?
4. Do I modify the `structured_metrics/plugins/statsd.py` file as we have fixed hierarchy across our distributed infrastructure?
5. Anything I am missing?
6. What will I have to change in my statsd? I quote the carbon-tagger documentation- *"aggregators like statsd will need proto2 support."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the structured metrics plugins will set the tags for proto1 ("old style") metrics, see https://github.com/vimeo/graph-explorer/wiki/Structured-Metrics

if you want to stick to proto1 you just have to create a plugin to tag your metrics see https://github.com/vimeo/graph-explorer/wiki/Structured-Metrics#writing-your-own-plugins and existing plugins for examples

you can basically ignore carbon-tagger if you want to stick with proto1, so 3 is not needed, but otherwise yes. the statsd plugin just converts statsd's internal metrics to proto2.

Comment: The issue is that i have around 1000 proto-1 metrics, out of which only ~250 are 'recognized' by graph-explorer once i run the `update.py` script. Perhaps because my metrics vary in depth. Some are 5 levels deep, whereas most are 10-12.

Comment: with "not recognized" do you mean recognized by the catchall plugins? that's not a problem.  all your metrics should be matched (by catchall plugins or regular plugins), I just added some code to git that says for every plugin, how many metrics it yielded.